# python django - error loading custom template tags

Tags: python, django, templates

I definitely doing something wrong but I'm not sure what!

In my django project, I created a folder called "templatetags", in that folder I have:

```
__init__.py
tags.py
```

In tags.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter("timestamp")
def timestamp(value):
    try:
        return datetime.fromtimestamp(value)
    except AttributeError:
        return ''
```

In one of my templates I call:

```
{{record.date|timestamp|date:"D d M Y"}}
```

Yet when I run the template I get the following output error:

```
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    
Invalid filter: 'timestamp'
```

Can someone let me know what I"m doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 things to check 
1. Is your app listed in INSTALLED_APPS
2. did you load the custom tag in the file? i.e `{% load tags %}`

Comment: You were correct, didn't have load tags in the template file. Is there no way around that?

Comment: Why do you want a way around it? Isn't "load tags" good enough?